# Knockout composite binding path

Tags: binding, path, knockout.js, composite

Hi I am trying to bind to an item within an object in knockout:

the following line does not work

```
<span data-bind="text:selectedItem.details"></span>
```

I tried changing it to have parenthesis after selecteItem:

```
<span data-bind="text:selectedItem().details"></span>
```

, it still did not work.

Using with:, however works:

```
<div data-bind="with:selectedItem">
    <span data-bind="text:details" />
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How does one use composite binding paths in Knockout.
Thanks

Comment: Does `selectedItem` have an initial value? If not, the second data binding will not work. If it *does* have an initial value it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, when I initialized the selected item the second method did work!

Comment: Please post your view model script. That will help determining how it is laid out. Even your model data that is being bound will throw some light. -Suj